# XSL Remove tag if temperature > 20 otherwise copy tag

Tags: xslt

So I have to transform this XSL with the condition if temperature > 20 remove tag otherwise copy temperature
So far I got something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<message-in>
    <realised-gps>
        <id>64172068</id>
        <resourceId>B-06- KXO</resourceId>
            <position>
                <coordinatesystem>Standard</coordinatesystem>
                <latitude>44.380765</latitude>
                <longitude>25.9952</longitude>
            </position>
        <time>2011-05- 23T10:34:46</time>
        <temperature>21.01</temperature> 
        <door>0</door>
    </realised-gps>
</message-in>
```

This is only removing the tag I can't make the otherwise or other if condition

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="temperature">
        <xsl:if test="temperature &gt; 20">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:if>           
        <xsl:if test="temperature &lt;= 20">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//temperature|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output File for temperature < than 20

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<message-in>
    <realised-gps>
        <id>64172068</id>
        <resourceId>B-06- KXO</resourceId>
            <position>
                <coordinatesystem>Standard</coordinatesystem>
                <latitude>44.380765</latitude>
                <longitude>25.9952</longitude>
            </position>
        <time>2011-05- 23T10:34:46</time>
        <temperature>15</temperature> 
        <door>0</door>
    </realised-gps>
</message-in>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing this....

```
<xsl:if test="temperature &gt; 20">
```

You need to do this...

```
<xsl:if test=". &gt; 20">
```

Because you are in a template matching `temperature` already, the test `temperature &gt; 20` is going to look for a child element also called `temperature`, when really all you want to check is the value of the current node.

Also, instead of doing this, which will end up recursively matching the same template

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//temperature|node()"/>
```

You can just do this....

```
<xsl:apply-templates />
```

So you template could look like this...

```
<xsl:template match="temperature">
        <xsl:if test=". &gt; 20">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:if>           
        <xsl:if test=". &lt;= 20">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

However, there is an easy way. Instead of the above template, simply be more specific with the template match for the node you wish to remove....

```
<xsl:template match="temperature[. &gt; 20]" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="temperature[. &gt; 20]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```